# Using English in Europe

Tags: international-travel, europe, language-barrier, english-language

I'm from the United States (born and raised) and have dual citizenship (Portugal). At some point, I want to spend time (more than just a vacation) in Europe. Linguistically, I feel confined to Portugal, Spain, France, Ireland, and (if I can improve a bit) Italy.

How much is English spoken around the EU? I assume the general rule is true that English is spoken in tourist areas, but I want to know about the "real" parts. Are there places where I can get by with only English? Most importantly, is it seen as [rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugly_American_(pejorative)) (acting like someone has to cater to me despite me being in their country) to use English?

Comment: An answer reminds me to advise: don't ask "Do you speak English?" Instead, ask a simple question in English and see how they respond. One thing that will go a long way is knowing how to say "hallo" and "thank you" in the local language.

Comment: What do you mean by "spend time"?  You can "get by" with English only for vacations or business trips anywhere in Europe, but that's quite different from actually *living* in a country and having to deal with taxes, driving licenses, garbage collection and all that fun stuff.

Comment: Also, Europe is so large and varied that I'm not sure we can give you a meaningful answer that covers everything from central Stockholm  to a rural village in Bulgaria.

Comment: Short answer depends: A LOT on the country/region. Northern Europe: great. Central: Very good, Southern: so-so at best. Eastern: limited. Generally better in urban centers than in the boonies. It's always acceptable to try English. If it doesn't work, Google Translate is your friend.

Comment: I used English on a week long trip in Poland as I don't know Polish. It was OK but difficult at times. Some people speak some English and some don't. My advice is just keep it simple if you're not sure. If you go to a receptionist at a hotel and say ''Can you call me a taxi to the airport?'', they should understand in theory.

Comment: @Hilmar this will depend a lot on how you're defining Central Europe. The Standing Committee on Geographical Names, Germany includes Western Romania and Ukraine in Central Europe, and Slovakia & Hungary are included by almost all sources, yet you're unlikely to reliably have "very good" English spoken in those areas

Comment: @Hilmar That might apply to holiday goers, but in real life for example France and Germany speak relatively little English, because their country is large and populous enough that they don't need English for anything. Whereas in Baltic countries you  mostly can't study in university without knowing English, it would be absolutely worthless to limit yourself to a teeny tiny language no one has written books in.

Comment: Depending on how you see  *"time (more than just a vacation)"*  your question might be more on-topic for the https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Stack Exchange site, because actually living abroad for longer than an (extended) holiday requires more than just finding *people* capable, willing and competent enough in English to be able to successfully communicate with. You will then also have to deal with *local bureaucracy, institutions, utility companies, contracts* etc. etc. and navigating those without a basic grasp of the local language will be easier or more challenging

Comment: It never hurts to first ask whether someone speaks english, preferably in the local language. Even in a country like the Netherlands, where nearly everyone is more than proficient and usually happy to help in english, not everyone appreciates getting 'ambushed' in a foreign language. Even a very broken *"Pardon, spreekt U Engels?"* will give your poor victim a moment to adjust to a foreign language.

Comment: OP: I *only* speak French, Portuguese, English, and Spanish. How can I possibly get around Europe?

Comment: @WeatherVane quite the contrary, I find that asking "Do you speak English?" in the native language helps a bit getting by and not looking that an ignorant redneck.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> How much is English spoken around the EU?

44% of EU inhabitants speak some level of English, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_the_European_Union:

| Official languages | [First language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_language) | [Additional language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_language) | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language) | 1% | **43%** | **44%** |
| [German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_language) | **20%** | 16% | 36% |
| [French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_language) | 14% | 16% | 30% |

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language_in_Europe mentions:

> In the EU25, working knowledge of English as a foreign language is clearly leading at 38%

Here is a map showing the percentage of people who have some "Knowledge of English" per country:

[image]

Legend: "Knowledge of English".

<sub>(Credits: By Knowledge_of_German_EU_map.svg: AlphathonTM(talk)Knowledge_English_EU_map.png: Aakerderivative work: AlphathonTM(talk) - Knowledge_of_German_EU_map.svgKnowledge_English_EU_map.png, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=11308478)</sub>

> Most importantly, is it seen as [rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugly_American_(pejorative)) (acting like someone has to cater to me despite me being in their country) to use English?

If some autochthon doesn't like that you speak English, it's their problem, not yours.

Comment: From a visitor's point of view, though, the number is considerably higher since people working in hotels, restaurants etc are far more likely to speak English, and they will not be interacting much with rural farmers, retirees, children etc who are less likely to speak English.

Comment: @lambshaanxy good point. Not to mention that people who can't speak English typically won't spontaneously speak to an English-speaking visitor.

Comment: "it's their problem, not yours" - well that depends on whether you are relying on them for something like getting your meal/catching a train/etc.

Comment: @lambshaanxy there are notable exceptions though - the former East Germany required me to dredge up my high school German rather quickly even in hotels and restaurants as I was dealing with people who grew up learning Russian as a second language. The young engineers I was working with of course spoke excellent English.

Comment: @ChrisH-UK When was that? The last generation that still got their entire school time in East Germany is close to retirement.

Comment: @quarague a few years ago now, but the people I was dealing with could have been in their 50s then, which fits. Or late 40s at least, and those well on the way through their school years wouldn't have had time to learn much English even if the curriculum changed overnight - which it probably didn't. I'd hazard a guess that those who'd joined their last school learning Russian would have carried on.

Comment: I was struck by how there didn't seem to be anyone young working in hospitality

Comment: @quarague Pupils started to learn Russian Language from fifth grade until 1990. Those people are 20 years away from retirement

Comment: I would note that there are disparities between locations, and age groups, which are not quite reflected in a single number. In France, for example, it's typically easier to find English-speaking people in touristy locations and cities, while harder out of the beaten path in the country side, and younger people are typically better at English (notably thanks to internet/games/netflix) than older people.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler But presumably at least those who entered high school/Gymnasium after 1990 would have added English then, if not earlier, pushing the limit back about five years for many.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I wonder how quickly they would have been able to recruit enough English teachers to work in the (former) East.  I visited the West in '93 and '95, and attitudes I saw suggested people wouldn't have been flocking to live and work in the East

Comment: I am a Bulgarian and would like to add that although the percent of English speakers appears low in Bulgaria a huge portion of the younger generation speaks English and additionally in practically all touristic places English will work. It is a bit different with government institutions where there is still a lot of room for improvement

Comment: @ChrisH-UK There were many English teachers in East Germany even before 1990. The language was taught as a second foreign language in many schools. Though they had less exchange with native speakers than the East German russian teachers or the West German English/French teachers, due to the traveling restricions.

Comment: @Arsak many, but I was assuming not enough to suddenly teach all kids to the sort of level that my contacts in the West reached in their teens

Comment: @ChrisH-UK: *"...  I'd hazard a guess that those who'd joined their last school learning Russian would have carried on."* At least at the Czech uni where I was studying when communism fell, almost everybody dropped Russian at the end of the semester (and we avoided most lessons even before the fall).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev However my experience of Bulgaria is that train stations, bus stations etc have essentially no English speaking employee, even in big cities like Sofia or Plovdiv, so people should keep google translate at the ready. Still well worth visiting your beautiful country (in fact I'll be in Varna in a week :))

Comment: @DenisNardin yes, the train stations are typically government run and quite possible you have issues. I am a bit surprised to hear about buses especially for big companies that also run international. If you find yourself in such situation, ask people around, maybe someone will be able to assist with translation

Comment: This graph is skewed as to how good the English skills are. I grew up in "East" Germany (former GDR) & received/hosted my international friends. IMHO, Poles speak better English & are able to hold in-depth conversation than us.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt *If some autochthon doesn't like that you speak English, it's their problem, not yours* - no, going to another country *expecting* them to speak English is your problem, not theirs. It’s also the reason why so many native English speakers’ language skills are poor / non-existent.

Comment: @Traveller I didn't write "going to another country expecting them to speak English". That's different and that'd be stupid.

Answer (score 17):

> Most importantly, is it seen as rude (acting like someone has to cater to me despite me being in their country) to use English?

Not in the Nordic countries and the Netherlands. Being Swedish, I can confirm almost anyone raised and schooled there will have (often near-native) fluency in English by their upper teens. If anything, many will take a degree of insult to being asked if they know English, as not being fluent, or even just having a strong accent, is widely looked down upon. So over there, zero problems whatsoever. I know the same goes for Denmark in particular.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147736/discussion-on-answer-by-crazydre-using-english-in-europe); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 13):

When you are a visitor, speaking English is acceptable all over Europe. It will not always easy but nobody expects a tourist to speak the local language and English is the most common foreign language in most of Europe. It may well be that in Spain, Italy and France you can get by with Portugese or however much you can remember of the local language better than English. But most tourist will speak English as first choice.

It is only in areas were English is the native language that you are going to have great difficulties finding people who can help you out if you do not speak the local language. There is less knowledge of a second language.

When staying for months or years, learning the local language is expected to essential.
Even in the Netherlands, where everyone with a secondary school education in the last 60 years can handle a simple conversation in English, for some things Dutch is essential, like the tax officials are not allowed to communicate with you in English, for legal reasons.

And while people are mostly willing and able to speak with you in English, conversations around you will be in the local language. So if you do not understand that you will feel locked out of the group.

How much of a problem you experience depends on the people you mix with, if it is only fellow expats it will be less of a problem, if it is only young people it is also less of a problem. But if you want to work with the elderly, like having a job in medical care, speaking the local language is essential.

Comment: You will struggle in large parts of Eastern Europe if you only speak English. They're much more used to German speaking tourists than English monoglots.

Comment: Depending on social circles, it is becoming more and more common that only a few speakers not being able to use the native language results in the whole group switching to English. I observe that each week with groups in inner city bars, restaurants or parks in Berlin. Ten years ago, I was working for a small game developer company, and one single Australian employee lead to the whole office using English at all times.

Comment: @JackAidley Outdated. Among younger Eastern Europeans who know a second language, this is normally English. German (or sometimes Russian) applies to the older generations

Comment: Perhaps things have changed in the last few years. This is my experience. There are far more German speaking tourists than English there so it makes sense for people who interact with tourists to learn it.

Comment: It all depends on the main language of visitors.  There are hotels in India where literally all the employees speak Punjabi quite well because they get a lot of visitors from the Punjabi-speaking region of India who refuse to learn the language of that region, it's a question of demand.

Comment: @JackAidley Smaller towns close to the Austrian/German border for sure, like Sopron. There I use German and basic Hungarian

Comment: @ccprog That makes sense as you want everyone in the room to follow the conversation?  Like I would use Spanish when talking to a friend from Spain but we would use English if my brother was in the conversation as he doesn't know Spanish.

Comment: If everyone in the group is involved in the same conversation it is likely to be in the common language. But in many groups the conversation is within a smaller part of the group and will be in the local language, especially if not all of the people in the group are fluent in English but often even when they are.

Comment: @Willeke, in large chain shops in Amsterdam, The Hague and Rotterdam (from personal experience) it's getting very common to be spoken to in English. If you then answer in Dutch the employees just stare at you, not knowing what you're saying.

Comment: Not just large chain shops, it is worse in touristy small shops.

Answer (score 10):

How easily you can get by in Europe depends very much on country. Broadly speaking, I find that Western and Northern Europe are very English friendly, and Eastern Europe (e.g. former Soviet countries) are not. The following is based on my experiences in various countries, YMMV:

Netherlands, Denmark, and Sweden: *almost everyone* speaks near perfect English, there is absolutely no problem at all conducting your business in English. In Copenhagen, people are (mildly) offended if you even ask if they speak English. So just open in English, and if they speak to you in Danish apologise and say you only speak English. However, whilst everyone speaks English: signs, menus, and attractions (e.g. museums, etc.) are often only in the local language outside of tourist spots.

Germany, Switzerland and Austria: heavily dependent on where you are. In Hamburg, Vienna, Cologne, Zurich or Berlin you will have no problem speaking English; however if you go into more rural locations you're much more likely to encounter shop staff, hotel staff, waiters, etc. who do not understand English or are uncomfortable speaking it with you.

France: much more English friendly than it used to be, and the famous French hostility to English speakers seems to have diminished. I've noticed a huge difference in ski-resorts, in particular. Still, even in tourist spots in Paris you'll encounter people who will not interact with you in English. However, if you know a handful of French words and are friendly you'll usually get by fine.

Czech, Hungary, Croatia, Slovenia, Slovakia: outside of the biggest cities and most touristy spots (e.g. you'll be fine in Prague), English friendly places are uncommon. However, we found almost all tourist facing people spoke enough German to get by.

I haven't spent enough time in Luxembourg or Belgium to form a view, since I've only ever stopped for lunch or fuel there, but the people we encountered spoke English so I think it's probably fine.

---

I invite others to edit to add countries I haven't covered (since I have no experience of them) here

Southern Europe (Spain, Portugal, Italy) is so-so. You can get by in larger cities but in the boonies and smaller cities it's hit or miss even with younger people. (Copied from comment by @hilmar)

Comment: Luxembourg and especially Brussels are very international, more or less everybody speaks English (and typically at least two more languages!)

Comment: Good answer: adding a few more countries: Southern Europe (Spain, Portugal, Italy) is so-so. You can get by in larger cities but in the boonies and smaller cities it's hit or miss even with younger people.

Comment: In France: you try to use English, and they answer in French. You try to speak French, and they answer in English.

Comment: This closely matches my experience. Scandinavians and the Dutch speak very good English, and in other countries it varies by area. I'll add that in Poland, there's a big difference by age: younger people generally speak at least basic English, while older people more commonly speak Russian or German.

Comment: @QuoraFeans That seems like a French thing, I know a French guy and he persistently tries to speak to Spanish tourists in Spanish, even though one of them literally spoke perfect English.

Comment: In Poland, I had much more luck using English with younger people.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I stopped for petrol in Luxemburg. The women in the station spoke to the first person in line in Dutch (I think?), the person in front of me in French, addressed me in German seeing the German numberplate on our car then switched to English when I replied in badly accented German. All without skipping a beat. Incredible.

Comment: In Greece and Cyprus: Generally no problems with English. Most people speak it adequately. Trying to get by with my limited Greek often resulted in people replying in English. This was primarily in Athens and on islands, which are by definition relatively touristy; no experience from actual _non_-touristy areas (which are harder to find in Greece than elsewhere).

Comment: @JackAidley Luxembourg has 3 official languages: French (almost everyone speaks it), German (about 3/4 of the population) and Luxembourgish (about 2/3. It is a German dialect with heavy influences from French and some from Dutch.). Many people speak all 3. In addition a lot of people have English as well.

Comment: Also, plenty of people travel in places like rural China where almost no one speaks in English. In practice you can get by just fine without knowing a single local word - gestures and Google Translate solve most problems just fine.

Comment: Or a phrase book in the right language, or even the pictures point it booklet.

Comment: *the famous French hostility to English speakers* → we have nothing about English *speakers*, these are the *English* we have a zillion of unfinished business with (anything post William I actually). And with Germans. And with Italians too. And Spanish. We are fine with Australians and Chileans. I think.

Comment: @WoJ, I have been in France many times, mostly in the company of people from the UK, sometimes US Americans or Canadians, other Dutch, Spanish , Italian and the odd German. I have never experienced any negative attitude to any of the nationalities by the French. I have noticed a lack of actually speaking foreign languages in past, but these days many of the younger people are pretty fluent in English and willing to use it.

Comment: @Willeke I should have ended the comment with a smiley. It was a joke on how we stereotypically see ourselves as the center of the universe (the center of the center being actually in Versailles) and how we hate the English because Jeanne d'Arc :) Of course, this has nothing to do with reality, we are very welcoming. Except the Parisians.  (no, I am kidding again). On a serious note, I was truly thrilled by how my children who had an exchange with a class from Germany interacted. This generation has eliminated all traces of war traumas between our countries

Answer (score 3):

You have Portuguese citizenship and mention spending "more than just a vacation".

I assume you mean re-locating for at least a short while. That means dealing with some level of administration (health care, address and driver's licence registration, taxes, ...). That's a bit more complicated than ordering a coffee.

In general, as you go towards the north of Euope and towards larger cities you'll find it easier.

A rural town in France or Italy, I wouldn't expect much English at all to be spoken in local administration.

In Amsterdam or Oslo I wouldn't be worried. In the middle, it depends, and is a bit of a gamble. Even in Berlin, reputed to be quite international, it is far from obvious that an administrative clerk would speak English.

That said, if you speak Portuguese, any latin language should come relatively easily, so that makes most of the south of Europe more accessible. (Especially as you allude to the fact that you may speak Spanish and a bit of Italian)

Answer (score 3):

I will have to contradict some of the answers and comments.  Yes, knowledge of English is widespread, but after spending seventeen months in Spain over my first five years of retirement, sleeping in at least 25 cities/villages and wandering around several others, I can assure you that there are villages where **no one** speaks anything other than Spanish.

But most of my time in Spain was along the Camino de Santiago, where hikers from over 150 countries travel.  I'd say at least half of those spoke pretty good English.  Especially the Dutch and the Germans.  The Dutch are required to learn another language in school, and most of them learn two.  Many of the Koreans who hike the Camino could not speak Spanish or English, but survived with their electronic translators.

Unless I misunderstood, you already speak French, Spanish, and Portuguese.  You should then have no problem in Italy or the Italian areas of Switzerland.  I can read French & Portuguese but not speak them, and my Spanish is probably only B1 or B2.  But that was enough to pass a sample A1 test in Italian.

Answer (score 2):

As an American, I found that in 2018, we were able to get by on my wife's 8th grade Spanish teacher level of Spanish (i.e. she taught first year Spanish), and the French I could dredge up from high school.

While my French was embarrassing, generally, once we were found to at least be making an effort, most of the people we dealt with would switch to English. Even if their English wasn't great, we managed to get along in just fine in Spain, Austria and France. An occasional visit to Google Translate was necessary for more difficult transactions, but that was quite rare, and we usually did that before we started for things we thought would be difficult.

We did stick with primarily touristy areas, though, so that would be fairly expected, but did interact with random people on the street, too, trying to find places, get food, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there places where I can get by with only English?

You can get by anywhere on the planet without speaking a word of the local language and without locals knowing a word of your native language. Google Translate works exceptionally great for most languages out there and gestures/drawings/hand signs fill the void where a translation falls short. Thousands of people have visited every country in the world - and I assure you they didn't have to learn the language of every country in order to make it happen.

So download Google Translate on your phone (it even has an offline version these days) and stop worrying about who does or doesn't speak English. It just doesn't matter and honestly... you just don't *need* to talk to that many people while traveling. It's nice to be able to strike up a conversation with a random farmer in rural Poland but your trip won't be ruined if the farmer only happens to speak Polish.

Comment: Millions of people traveled before computer translation existed, even before computers existed. Yes a translation tool/phrase book can be helpful but it is not essential.

Comment: @Willeke definitely, see: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/19318/historically-how-did-people-living-in-distant-regions-communicate. But I do think that just because our ancestors have suffered doesn’t mean we should suffer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been to every country in Europe, but according to the EF English Proficiency Index on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EF_English_Proficiency_Index I have visited several countries with very high English proficiency levels. The Netherlands, Norway and Sweden are ranked as having "very high proficiency" and I was able to get by using only English during my visits to these countries.
I have also been to the Czech Republic, which is ranked 26th with high proficiency. While I could still get by using only English in tourist areas of Prague, this was only true for tourist spots. According to the article "Hiring A Guide In The Czech Republic: Pros & Cons" https://gowithguide.com/blog/hiring-a-guide-in-the-czech-republic-pros-cons-5572 only about 10% of Czechs speak English in the country. Therefore, when visiting off-the-beaten-path attractions, I needed to learn some Czech or hire a guide.
Spain is ranked 35th with moderate proficiency. My experience there was similar - but encountered fewer English speakers than in Prague.